# Compactness of space of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> We are given $(X,\rho)$ -- the metric space of all sequences $x_n\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $|x_n|\leq 2^{-n}$ and $$\rho(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n}-y_{n})^2} = \sqrt{\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n}-y_{n})^2}.$$  Prove that $(X,\rho)$ is a compact space.

The first thought I had: to take arbitrary sequence of sequences and to use Bolzano-Weierstrass in every component, however knowing how close a component to a corresponding one in the resulting sequence means nothing as the number N, from which the inequality must hold can be different for every component (and since there are infinitely many of them, this sequence of N's can be unbounded).

Then I thought of using Bolzano-Weierstrass with Cauchy sequences in order to prove the space to be complete. Then match $x_n$ with binary sequence corresponding to inequalities $2^{-j}\leq x_{n}\leq 2^{-j+1}$ and choose set of sequences that start with $1$ or $0$ depending on which of these have infinitely many elements in it.

But I was tired and maybe didn't notice how to proceed from here. Can you give any hints?

Comment: Do you know about diagonal extraction?

Comment: No; I would like to use some simple facts, like space is compact <=> in every sequence there is convergent subsequence or compactness <=> totally bounded & complete